# Linking User with model in lift mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, lift

In my model I did the following:

```
object ownerId extends StringRefField(this, User, 120)
```

and in the code:

```
def render = {
".count *" #> posts.length &
".posts *" #> posts.map { p =>
  ".post *" #> Unparsed(p.body.get.replaceAll("\n", "<br>")) &
    ".time *" #> TimeHelpers.hourFormat(p.at.get) &
    ".user *" #> p.ownerId.obj.map ({ u =>
      ".username *" #> u.username.get &
        ".avatar *" #> Gravatar.imgTag(u.email.get, 64)

    })
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
<div class="lift:comet?type=PostActor">
    <div class="count"></div>
    <div class="posts">
        <div class="media well">
            <div class="user">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#"> <span class="avatar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading"><span class="username"></span></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p><span class="post"></span></p>
            <small><span class="time"></span></small>

        </div>
    </div>
```

generated html is set of nested  posts

```
<div class="posts">
        <div class="media well">

            <p>
                hi

            </p>
            <small>23:39:10</small>

        </div>
    </div><div class="posts">
```

the problem is user details does not display, can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you post the html output it's generating? I don't know precisely what you refer to by "user details."

Comment: Btw you're essentially rendering p.body via Unparsed, which means you're open to script injection etc. Better do something like p.body.get.split("\n").map(s => <p>{ s }</p>), or the like.

Comment: html output: <div class="posts">
   <div class="media well">
    
    <p>
     hi

    </p>
    <small>23:39:10</small>

   </div>
  </div><div class="posts">
   <div class="media well">
    
    <p>
     hiii
    </p>
    <small>12:07:20</small>

   </div>
  </div><div class="posts">
   <div class="media well">
    
    <p>
     hey
    </p>
    <small>11:08:29</small>

   </div>
  </div><div class="posts">

Comment: when I tried `".username" #>  p.ownerId.obj.get.username &
          ".avatar" #> Gravatar.imgTag(p.ownerId.obj.get.email.get, 64)` I got `[ERROR] net.liftweb.actor.ActorLogger - Actor threw an exception`

Comment: Clearly, `p.ownerId.obj == Empty`. Is it `NULL` in the database?

Comment: no database is alright I checked it out

Comment: Okay so I don't know what the issue is but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with templating. Can you verify that p.ownerId.obj.isEmpty == true? And if yes, please create a new question or update this question, with the details relevant to how you load the data, and leaving out the eliminated templating part.

Comment: @nafg sorry for being late and yes it gives true how can I deal with that?

Comment: Clearly the issue has nothing to do with templating / css selector transforms: it's a lift-record question. So I think it makes sense to open a new question, and give all the details relevant to how your trying to materialize the data.